# Arrays of pointers to arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm using a library which for one certain feature involves variables like so:

```
extern const u8 foo[];
extern const u8 bar[];
```

I am not allowed to rename these variables in any way.

However, I like to be able to access these variables through an array (or other similar method) so that I do not need to continually hardcode new instances of these variables into my main code.

My first attempt at creating an array is as follows:

```
const u8* pl[] = {
    &foo,
    &bar
};
```

This gave me the error `cannot convert 'const u8 (*)[]' to 'const u8*' in initialization`, and with help elsewhere along with some Googling, I changed my array to this:

```
u8 (*pl)[] = {
    &foo,
    &bar
};
```

Upon compiling I now get the error `scalar object 'pl' requires one element in initializer`.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Don't take the address of the arrays - just use the array variable in the initializers and they'll decay into pointers.

Comment: Do you want to access the _variables_ or the arrays they represent?  That's a little nuance that makes a huge difference (cfr. Neil Butterworth's answer)

Comment: Both would probably be fine. Well, truthfully, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An array of pointers to arrays only works if `foo` and `bar` have exactly the same size, and that size is known at compile time in your translation unit.

```
const u8 (*pl[])[32] = {&foo, &bar};
```

If that is not the case, you must use an array of pointers to bytes.

```
const u8 *pl[] = {foo, bar};
```

Comment: You can have pointers to incomplete types (such as arrays of unknown size) in an array, you just can't have arrays of incomplete types.

Comment: @Charles And how would you use that in a meaningful way without getting an `invalid use of array with unspecified bounds` error?

Comment: @FredOverflow: I'm not sure what you mean? The same way as you'd use `foo` or `bar` directly which are also arrays of unspecified bounds. Like can still do `foo[x]`, so you can do `(*pl[0])[x]` so long as `x` is actually in range. You can't check it, but if it's valid it'll work.

Comment: Alright, I'll be marking this as accepted (second snippet), but can I ask - is there any theory to be learnt in relation to pointers and arrays in this respect?

Comment: @a2h: Certainly there is theory to be learned; such as, it is legal to have an array of pointers to incomplete types even if this answer says it isn't ;) .  The basic principle is that arrays are not pointers but the name of an array decays to a pointer to its first element in most expression contexts (as arguments to `sizeof` and unary `&` being the obvious exceptions). This should be covered by any good basic C or C++ textbook.  I personally find the explanation of arrays and pointers in K & R among the clearest.

Comment: @a2h It would say the lesson is that pointers to arrays rarely make sense, but it's still a good idea to know them! Sadly, many C programmers confuse 2D arrays, arrays of pointers and pointers to arrays, based on the erroneous assumption that arrays and pointers are the same.

Answer (score 2):

As the arrays don't have a size in their declaration is there any reason you can't just an array of pointers to their first elements?

E.g.

```
const u8* pl[] = { foo, bar };
```

If you wanted an array of pointers to arrays I think that you would need to do:

```
const u8 (*pl[])[] = { &foo, &bar };
```

but I don't see that it really has any advantage over the previous solution.

Comment: A reason? Well, that'd be my lack of knowledge. I'll give your solution a try and see how it goes...

Answer (score 1):

```
extern const int a[];

const int *  aa[] = { a };
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the &. An array decays normally into a pointer.

```
typedef int u8;  // Using int as I don't know what a u8 is.

const u8 foo[] = { 1, 2, 3};
const u8 bar[] = { 1 };

const u8* pl[] = {
    foo,
    bar
};
```